# Create a blinds effect in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

What would be an easy way to create Venetian blinds effect in Silverlight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the [Expression Blend SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=3062) and use the `BlindsTransitionEffect`.

Comment: Hi Anthony, thanks for your response. I have Expression Blend 4 installed, and couldn't find the BlindsTransitionEffect. Can you advise where to check it?

Comment: @Rahul: You need to add the Micrsoft.Expression.Effects.dll to your project.  However have Blend 4 you ought to be able to find it in its UI somewhere.  Perhaps you still need to install the SDK, I don't have blend so I don't whether the SDK is included in it.

Comment: Do you happen to have any samples?

Comment: @Rahul: Watch: http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/SilverlightTV/Creating-Rich-Interactions-Using-Blend-4-Transition-Effects-Fluid-Layout-and-Layout-States-Silverlig/